# How to convert a branch to master with EGit?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I created a branch a month ago, and during this month I have been coding and committing to the project on my branch.

The code in the master branch is now obsolete, and what I want to do is to convert my branch into the new master branch, without merging in the old code from the old master branch (because it doesn't have any sense).

Does someone know how to do that in Eclipse with EGit?

Comment: Why not delete the obsolete commits and then rebase what you like to have in master?

Comment: Just do `git branch -f master your-branch-name` from the commandline